# Show more items where paginate

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to paginate results, I got the last id showed ($id), and I put `where('id', '<', $id)` and `orderBy('id', 'desc')` in model, but not working...

```
    public function user_load_more($id, $friendly_url)
    {
$user = User::where('friendly_url', '=', $friendly_url)
    ->with('userProfile.get_following')
    ->with(['shares_load_more' => function($query) use($id) {
    $query->where('id', '<', $id);
    }])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->first();

        return view("site.list.user.links", compact("user"));
    }
```

MODEL:

```
public function shares_load_more()
{
return $this->hasMany(Share::class, 'user_id', 'id')->select('id', 'link_id', 'user_id', 'shared_in', 'content', 'created_at')->take(3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->where('type', '=', 0);
}
```

But this return the same last items, no continue the where not working...

Showed:

```
1
2
3
```

Next showed:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: could you please elaborate further like what it is showing, how you showing?? how you are calling paginate for next items??

Comment: isn't there a laravel paginate(number) function or why won't you use, limit and offset in queries? Seems like a complex approach to a simple problem.

Comment: Looks like your `$query->where('id', '<', $id);` constraints only inside your relation, not the user itself. Is that wanted?

Comment: Yes is inside of the relation, but no works...

Answer (score 0):

“Don’t reinvent the wheel again”.

We use framework like laravel to ease our work. So laravel has built in way to do this instead of building it from scratch.

See how easy it actually is….

```
public function user_load_more($id, $friendly_url)
    {
$user = User::where('friendly_url', '=', $friendly_url)
    ->with('userProfile.get_following')
    ->with(// ……………)
    ->paginate(3);

        return view("site.list.user.links", compact("user"));
    }
```

Your view should look like this,

```
<div class="container">
    @foreach ($users as $user)
         // user detail
    @endforeach
</div>
{{ $users->links() }}
// this will show the next links
```

Try this.

[Database: Pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/pagination)

Still you needed to try your own code, I feel like your model just return same 3 results every time.